# AbstractGatewayFilterFactory kotlin implementation dont receive config parameter

Tags: spring, kotlin, filter, config, gateway

I wrote custom gateway filter on kotlin with config class, but when i start app got exception.

```
@Component
class UserRequestLimiterFilter(
    @Lazy var userRequestAttemptRepository: UserRequestAttemptRepository
) : AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<UserRequestLimiterFilter.Config>(Config::class.java){
    
    data class Config(
        var limit: Int
    )

    override fun apply(config: Config): GatewayFilter {
        return GatewayFilter { exchange, chain ->
            ///
    }
}
```

config:

```
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: categories-route
          uri: ${event-service.url}
          predicates:
            - Path=/category/public/**
          filters:
            - UserRequestLimiterFilter=10
```

exception:

```
2023-09-27T01:32:57.947+03:00 ERROR 7282 --- [           main] o.s.c.gateway.route.CachingRouteLocator  : Refresh routes error !!!

org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to ru.slicetech.addesk.gateway.filters.UserRequestLimiterFilter$Config
/////
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to ru.slicetech.addesk.gateway.filters.UserRequestLimiterFilter$Config:

    Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to ru.slicetech.addesk.gateway.filters.UserRequestLimiterFilter$Config

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I tried different types of definition filter property and config class but not working